# DC Motor driver with Arduino

Tags: arduino, motor, driver

I made a simple motor driver as suggested [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/motor-driver-using-only-2n2222-transistor)

```
+12V ---------+---------+          
              |         |
             / \        |
             |M| motor ---  1N4001
             \ /       / \
              |         |
              +---------+
              |
            |/
CTL -/\/\/--|    2N2222 NPN       
      1k    |\>
              |
             ---
              -
```

How do I connect and control this with and Arduino?

Could you please post instructions or direct me to some links I may find useful.

Comment: I think this belongs in the original question.

Comment: The CTL signal turns the motor on or off. Set the output of your arduino connected to this pin high to turn the motor on, and set it low to turn the motor off.

Comment: @THomasO, you can vote to close as duplicate if you think it is.

Comment: @Kortuk, I'm not sure it's a duplicate - but more an extension of the original question that belongs on the original question page.

Comment: I think it's a new question - "How to I control that driver with an Arduino"

Comment: @ThomasO, that is the definition of a duplicate that you just told me. If it should be with the first, vote to close as duplicate. I am a moderator and trying to avoid closing everything, more trying to get the community to vote for closing, remember, you will not close it on your own. It takes 4 more people agreeing, or s/he will see the vote to close and will edit his question to show why s/he considers it a different topic.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7296/connecting-h-bridge-with-arduino-closed this question was closed for not enough detail, what makes you think asking it again will help?

Comment: @kellenjb, in this question he actually referenced a schematic, I would bet people do not vote close it for detail.

Comment: @kortuk, its still a duplicate regardless. He can vote to reopen the other and add detail. Instead hes just creating lots of duplication.

Comment: Surely, this is a different question, that's not an H-Bridge

Comment: @joby taffey true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
+12V ---------+---------+          (Connect to the Vin or 9v on the Arduino)
              |         |
             / \        |
             |M| motor ---  1N4001
             \ /       / \
              |         |
              +---------+
              |
            |/
CTL -/\/\/--|    2N2222 NPN        (Connect CTL to your Digital out pin)
      1k    |\>
              |
             ---
              -                    (Connect this to Gnd)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Beginner question; but that really confused me for quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the control pin for your motor driver to a digital output pin of the Arduino, 13 is a good choice.
Connect the Arduino's ground pin to the ground of your driver.

Here's an Arduino sketch to loop, turning it on and off.

```
int CTLPin = 13;                 // CTL connected to digital pin 13

void setup()
{
  pinMode(CTLPin, OUTPUT);      // sets the digital pin as output
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(CTLPin, HIGH);   // sets the motor on
  delay(1000);                  // waits for a second
  digitalWrite(CTLPin, LOW);    // sets the motor off
  delay(1000);                  // waits for a second
}
```