# Using motors with arduino without external hardware

Tags: arduino, dc-motor

I have three small motors, and I know you should use a motor shield or driver when working with the arduino, but would it be safe to use these with the arduino by themselves without a shield? And if so, what would be the best way to work with them and control their speed?
[image: the motors]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will damage the Arduino chip if you connect a motor directly to one of the outputs. I've used the [Adafruit motor shield](http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=81) with motors like that.

Comment: Ok, it's weird though, I bought an arduino kit and it came with the motors, but did not provide a motor shield. It is safe to run a servo without a shield though, correct?

Comment: If your kit came with a transistor - http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/motor-driver-using-only-a-2n2222-transistor

Comment: Yes it did. I guess that explains it.

Comment: Although I use H-Bridges nowadays, when I first started, I plugged brushed motors in directly to outputs and it didn't damage anything as far as I can tell. This was a few years back and it's the only arduino I have. I think these ATmegas are pretty dang tough.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible...

The Arduino can not drive that type of motor - the start up surge would damage the chip, also a diode is needed to handle the 'back emf' when the motor is turned off.

A servo has internal electronics to switch the motor. you just provide a repeating pulse of the correct length.