# Using MBED PWM for motor control

Tags: transistors, mbed

I have an [*mbed*](http://mbed.org/handbook/Homepage) project with firmware that controls some [`PwmOut`](http://mbed.org/handbook/PwmOut) switches. All works fine firmware opens and closes switches as expected. I tested this with a LED (and resistor).

Now my goal is that instead of a light coming on, a electric brush motor (with a simple +/-) 3v-5v should run. I understand that the `PwmOut` from the *mbed* will not provide enough current to run the motor.

Will I need a transistor that connects the `PwmOut` port with the motor?

If yes:

- how do I know what type I need?
- these three legged guys - how are they hooked up?

Comment: It's worth adding how much current the motor draws (or a datasheet if you're not sure). If it's a small motor you could probably use the circuit from the answer to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/motor-driver-using-only-a-2n2222-transistor

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the recipe at http://mbed.org/cookbook/Motor which uses the `Motor` interface for driving a standard DC motor with PWM and an H-Bridge.

[image]

If, instead of using the L293D dual H bridge driver, you want to use a transistor to drive the motor. You choose the transistor mainly by looking for a switching transistor which has a current and voltage rating that exceed the current and voltage ratings of the motor (so it depends on the motor) - for high currents you may need a heatsink for the transistor.

For a bipolar junction transistor (BJT) you'll need a resistor to limit base current. Most driver circuits incorporate a diode to prevent harm to the transistor from back-EMF from the motor windings.

[image]

The connections to a BJT are base, emitter, and collector

[image]

You can find out which leg is which by looking at the data sheet for the specific transistor you have chosen. For [example](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/TIP120.pdf)

[image]

You can instead use a MOSFET, these can be more efficient (lower voltage drop when 'on')

Some rather good instructions can be found [here](http://www.me.umn.edu/courses/me2011/handouts/motor_control.pdf)